# CSS class in wordpress menu does not work

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to apply custom styling on my navigation menu in wordpress but when i assign a css class in appearance -> menus and style the class that i have assigned to the menu link no changes happen. I am trying to apply display: none to menu item and it shows the class and styling when the element is inspected but i dont know why it does not overwrite, replace and work. Theme i am using is Divi.

[image: screenshot css definition]

[image: screenshot css definition]

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: add parent class for `menu-segment-frezovanie`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add parent class for `menu-segment-frezovanie` like below.

```
body #top-menu li.mega-menu ul li.menu-segment-frezovanie{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the precedence of id `#` is higher then the class `.` so you need to target with id as its previously targeted like

```
#top-menu li.mega-menu ul li.menu-segment-frezovanie{
  display: none !important;
}
```